# Must, or at least may, a comma be placed whenever a verb might be mistaken for a part of a would-be compound noun?

Tags: commas

To clarify with a made-up example:

> When you address the nation state ...

Above, 'state' could be taken as either

- a part of an open compound noun ('nation state', see footnote), or
- a verb ('to state').

As a non-native speaker I notice that such ambiguous interpretations do briefly hinder my reading flow, as I have to retract a bit. Also, similar ambiguous cases don't seem that rare. Hence, ***must*, or at least *may*, one use a comma to disambiguate such cases?** In the running example, is this allowed (or even required)?

> When you address the nation, state ....

Comment: Please provide a full sentence. A fragment isn't always clear enough.  But a comma is a good idea there.

Comment: Certainly a comma 'may' be used where you would make a slight pause when speaking, or to avoid a possible ambiguity.

Comment: Normally, punctuation would disambiguate, but since "notification state" is unlikely to be taken as a compound word, it's not essential here. It would help, though, if you could provide some context.

Comment: *Notification state* **could** be a compound word in some technical context, but a real-life example, with its context, would be a better basis here. I can certainly see a terse instruction like "To address the notification state the purpose of your action" might be a bit garden-pathy. But made-up examples are almost always poor substitutes for real-life problems.

Comment: *As a non-native speaker ...* Rest assured, native speakers also occasionally stumble (mentally) when reading sentences such as you show us the first part of, but we stumble over sentences not parts of sentences. Without knowing what happens next in your text it's difficult to recommend what you might do.

Comment: This is required by Grice's Maxim of manner (clarity), specifically 
submaxims (2) _Avoid ambiguity – i.e., avoid language that can be interpreted in multiple ways_
 and (4b)
_Be orderly – i.e., provide information in an order that [a] makes sense, and [[4]b] makes it easy for the recipient to process it_. [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle#:~:text=Accordingly%2C%20the%20cooperative%20principle%20is,in%20pursuit%20of%20effective%20communication.)] The garden path _is_ best avoided (I've switched the example). // As for 'must' ... there's no punctuation czar.

Comment: No, this: "When you address the nation state etc"  does not provide context. But last time I looked no one *addresses a  nation state* in any case.

Comment: My advice: find the verb first.

Comment: Note that Grice's Maxims apply to conversations, i.e, oral speech taken in turns between two people. Their application to writing is much more complex, especially since every written sentence is multiply ambiguous (as computer parsers have discovered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an introductory adverbial infinitive (an infinitive of purpose). Such a thing is usually followed by a comma, so your *notification state* ambiguity would never see the light of day anyway:

> *To address the notification, state your name and number.*
>
> *To address the notification state, press the return key.*

Some style guides allow for the omission of the comma after a short and clear adverbial infinitive. For example:

> When introducing a sentence with an adverbial infinitive phrase, add a
> comma after it.
>
> <sub>Correct: *To study for the exam, I left the party and went home
> early.*</sub>
>
> <sub>Incorrect: **To study for the exam I left the party and went
> home early.*</sub>
>
> It is possible to drop the comma if the introductory phrase is clear
> and short (no more than three or four words).
>
> <sub>Correct: *To learn Spanish you need to be consistent.*</sub>
>
> <sub>Source:
> [PristineWord](https://www.pristineword.com/comma-adverbial-infinitive-phrase/)</sub>

As you can see, your example fails both the short and clear tests. Use the comma and carry on.